# why long long is not int64_t but they have same size?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I tried this on my computer

```
std::cout << std::is_same<int64_t, long long>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same<int64_t,  long>::value;
std::cout << sizeof(long);
std::cout << sizeof(long long);
std::cout << sizeof(int64_t);
```

and the result is `false, true, 8, 8, 8`

I know `int64_t` is exactly 64 bit, and it shows `long` is same as `int64_t`, but `long long` is different from `int64_t` and it is also 64bit. Why could this happen?

**EDIT**

Can I use `long long` and `int64_t` interchangeably on my machine, given that they are both integer types and have same size?

Comment: `long` and `long long` are different types despite having the same size

Comment: double also has the size 8, but..

Comment: @M.M    i know `long` could be 32bit on some machines ...  but what are the differences when both `long` and `long long` are 64 bits?

Comment: They're different types . I'm not sure what else you are asking. You cannot use `long long` and `int64_t` interchangeably.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`long` and `long long` are built-in types defined by the core language.

`int64_t` is defined by the `<cstdint>` header (in practice include `<stdint.h>`). It's defined as an alias for some built-in type. In your case it's defined as an alias for `long`.

---

Built in types that *can* be the same size on some platform still need to be regarded as distinct types in order to not create ambiguous calls of overloaded functions.

There are even built in numerical types that guaranteed have the same size and signedness, but still are distinct. Namely, all three of `unsigned char`, `char` and `signed char` are distinct and of size 1, but `char` must be the same signedness as one of the others. Although I don't recommend doing it, technically you can freely overload functions based on just this difference.

---

Re

> **”** Can I use `long long` and `int64_t` interchangeably on my machine, given that they are both integer types and have same size?

That depends on what you mean by “interchangeably”.

Since `int64_t` with your compiler is an alias for `long`, you can't call a function expecting an `int64_t*`, with a `long long*` pointer.

But `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, and in this sense it's only with respect to readability that it matters which of `long long` and `int64_t` you choose.

Answer (score 0):

[3.9.1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf)

> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short
>   int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int"

[18.4.1] of the same says that

> using int64_t = signed integer type ; // optional

So you are looking at two distinct basic types and comparing them to the type alias. 
In your case its `int64_t` is aliased with `long` however there could be an implementation when its aliased with `long long int`

---

As for you extra question, it depends what do you mean by interchangeability,  `long long` is at least as long as a `long` but in theory or in future could be 'longer', using these types interchangeably would still required type casting

Comment: You'll need to go into more detail here in order to answer the question